# SpriteKit partial texture mapping

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

Is it possible to create a `SKSpriteNode` that displays only a part of a texture?

For example, can I create a square with size **100x100** displaying the specific region of a texture of size **720x720** like from `x1=300` to `x2=400` and `y1=600` to `y2=700`?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can do this with SKCropNode : https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skcropnode

Comment: do you want the entire sprites body to display the full texture, or do you want a sprite with a full texture only display a part of the sprite body?

Comment: What I am trying to do is a puzzle game; get a texture and create squares from this texture each displaying different parts of the texture.

Comment: ok I will give you an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to break up a texture into smaller chunks of textures to be used as puzzle pieces, then you want to use `SKTexture(rect: in texture:)`

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
let texture = SKTexture(...)  //How ever you plan on getting main texture
let subTextureRect = CGRect(x:0,y:0.width:10,height:10) // The actual location and size of where you want to grab the sub texture from main texture
let subTexture = SKTexture(rect:subTextureRect, in:texture);
```

You now have a chunk of the sub texture to use in other nodes.

Comment: Thank you! It worked nicely after modifying the rect values. These posts helped too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228104/what-is-happening-to-my-sprite-when-using-initrectintexture.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874822/trying-to-use-only-a-portion-of-a-sktexture-using-texturewithrect-intexture.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

   let visibleArea = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: CGSize(width:100,height:100))

   let parentNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .white, size: CGSize(width:200, height:200))

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let cropNode = SKCropNode()

        let texture = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")

        visibleArea.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        cropNode.maskNode = visibleArea

        cropNode.addChild(texture)

        addChild(cropNode)


    }


    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            let previousPosition = touch.previousLocation(in: self)

                let translation = CGPoint(x: location.x - previousPosition.x , y: location.y - previousPosition.y )

                visibleArea.position = CGPoint(x: visibleArea.position.x + translation.x , y: visibleArea.position.y + translation.y)
        }
    }
}
```

Overriden touchesMoved method is there just because of better example. What I did here, is:

- created SKCropNode
- added a texture to it which will be masked
- defined visible area which is SKSpriteNode and assigned it to crop node's mask property, which actually does the magic

Here is the result:

[image: masking]

Comment: I know I have to avoid commands like this but I have to say it; thanks so much!

Comment: I tried it but couldn't make it work. Still thanks though since I learned to use cropping while testing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It can also be implemented as a common ScrollView.